# Can't get detailed deleted with soft delete feature in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using soft delete feature in laravel, it is ok when I load all data with `Post::withTrashed()->get()` method. But when I want to get the detailed information of the data using this query `Post::withTrashed()->find($post)->get()`, it throws me to 404 page. Please help.

I tried `Post::onlyTrashed()->find($post)->get()` too, but still the same.

I checked the routes file by directly echoing a Hello world string on it and does work normally.

**UPDATE**

Controller script.

```
public function fetchDeletedPosts()
{
    return Post::onlyTrashed()->paginate(10);
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Post  $post
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit(Post $post)
{
    $posts = Post::withTrashed()->find($post)->first();
    return view('post.edit', compact('posts'));
}
```

web.php script

```
Route::get('posts/deleted', 'PostController@fetchDeletedPosts')->name('posts.removed');
Route::get('posts/deleted/{post}/edit', 'PostController@edit');
```

Post.php script

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Post extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'category_id', 'status', 'slug', 'title', 'content-preview', 'content'
    ];

    public function getRouteKeyName() {
        return 'slug';
    }

    public function author() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function tags() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: 404 means page not found. Check your routes.

Comment: tried `->where()`? i'm afraid `withTrashed` returns a builder rather than model where `find` works.. cmiiw

Comment: @FelippeDuarte , I did explain this in my question. The routes is fine, I can grab the undeleted data

Comment: @BagusTesa , where function also doesn't allow me to reach the soft deleted data, it sends me to 404 too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel dependency injection container will already fetch the data for you. But you have a deleted post. That's why you got a 404.
So change your route to:

```
Route::get('posts/deleted/{id}/edit', 'PostController@edit');
```

And your controller to

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $posts = Post::withTrashed()->find($id);
    return view('post.edit', compact('posts'));
}
```

Comment: @Fellipe , It worked, thanks. But when I use `slug` instead of `id`,  It still gave me 404.

Comment: You can query by the slug: `Post::withTrashed()->where('slug',$slug)->first()`. Just replace `id` for `slug` both in route and function parameter

Comment: @Fellipe , It worked! Thanks. Let's go to starb*cks someday, haha